# requests.post to hastebin.com not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to use the `requests` module from python to make a post in http://hastebin.com/

but I've been failing and doesn't know what to do anymore. is there any way I can really make a post on the site? here my current code:

```
import requests

payload = "s2345"

headers = {
    'Host': 'hastebin.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '5',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Origin': 'http://hastebin.com',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Referer': 'http://hastebin.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    }

req = requests.post('http://hastebin.com/',headers = headers, params=payload)


print (req.json())
```

Comment: Why are you specifying *all* the headers? Your payload certainly isn't JSON either.

Comment: Did you have any documentation about what kind of payload the server really expects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over the [provided `haste` client code](https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-client/blob/master/lib/haste/uploader.rb) the server expects a raw post of the file, without a specific content type. The client also posts to the `/documents` path, not the root URL.

They are also not being picky about headers, just leave those all to `requests` to set; the following works for me and creates a new document on the site:

```
import requests

payload = "s2345"

response = requests.post('http://hastebin.com/documents', data=payload)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json()['key'])
```

Note that I used `data` here, not the `params` option which sets the *URL query paramaters*.